# Is state variable $S$ is continuous as parameter vary for a system of differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity, nonlinear-system

Given, simple model,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}S}{\mathrm{d}t} &=& -\beta SI    \\ \nonumber
  \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} &=& \beta SI - \gamma I \\ \nonumber
  \frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t} &=&  \gamma I
\end{eqnarray}$$

Is variable $S$ continuous with respect to $\beta$, if one vary $\beta$?

My thoughts : if I vary $\beta$ very small, then rate of change become also small, but i doubt is it possible only for after small amount of time or for after large amount of time also.

Is there suitable way to describe it?